# Url paramter with a value with two words

Tags: django, url

I have a problem calling an url, i want to know whats the way to pass a value with 2 words like an argument or if my question is not possible

i have this in my **url.py:**

```
url(r'^tiendas/([\w-]+)/$', MostrarTiendas.as_view(), name='mostrartiendas'),
```

i want to pass a value called name_tienda but this field sometimes have 2 word and django return this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
http://localhost:8000/tiendas/Tienda%20Amiga
```

thank for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your url regex to this:

```
url(r'^tiendas/(?P<name_tienda>[-\w]+))', MostrarTiendas.as_view(), name='mostrartiendas'),
```